# How to change text localization “I'm not a robot” in recaptcha?

Tags: localization, customization, captcha, recaptcha, personalization

On different PC I see different localizations for `I'm not a robot` lable although I locates within one city. Aim - always to show same test distincts from  `I'm not a robot`

I have wrote following code to change label `I'm not a robot` in recaptcha.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#recaptcha-anchor-label").text("Something different.");
    });
</script>
```

maybe problem related with Iframe?

Can you help to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to force language if use following url:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=YOUR_LOCALE'></script>
```

Comment: this doesn't change the text, simply translate into other languages

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change that specific text because it belongs to a third party `iframe`, though there is a workaround that fulfils exactly what you're asking for.

You can append a new `div` on the parent `div` you can control, aligning and overlapping it on the label text, considering the Google Captcha has always a fixed size. Therefore, [according to documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), considering you may have the main Captcha `div` on your code with `class="g-recaptcha"`, you simply do:

```
$('.g-recaptcha').append('<div id="new_label"></div>');  
$('#new_label').text("My custom text");
$('#new_label').css({"position":"absolute", "width":"160px", "top":"27px", "left":"53px", "background-color":"#f9f9f9"});
```

**it works :)**

[image]